# Smooth a curve in mesh while maintaining its current angle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I've got a panel here which needs smoothing off but I'm not sure how to do it? The second image is rendered and you can clearly see the edges. It is supposed to look somewhat like the panel in the 3rd picture which is the real bed.

I've supplied the panel pre-bevel and pre-inset as well as the one in the pictures below in the .blend.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a subsurf modifier on your object. You will need first to triangulate your mesh (manually of with modifier as you want) since ngon will give strange results around the holes.

Before
[image]
With subsurf
[image]
Ngon problem with subsurf
[image]
Triangulate
[image]

Comment: Sorry, just seen the modifiers on the right. Did you select the faces around the hole in the last pic to apply the triangulate modifier?

Comment: No, modifier are applied to the complete mesh. If you add the same modifier stack there is nothing else to do (exept maybe to change the crease of some edges if you want to sharpen them, but it is not your case for this object.